# IEnumerator yielding to the result of another IEnumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have two classes set up in my project.

On a button press in the first class I am calling the first `IEnumerator` on a button press:

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(250, 0, 100, 20), "clear"))
{
   StartCoroutine(Foo.test());
}
```

The method being called looks like this (in the other class):

```
public static IEnumerator test()
{     
    yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache());
    // do stuff
}
```

However, I'm intending this method to only carry out its actions once it gets a return from a second `IEnumerator` that pings a server and waits a few seconds to get a result.

This method looks like so:

```
IEnumerator  DownloadAndCache ()
{
    // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
    while (!Caching.ready)
        yield return null;

    Debug.Log("downloading asset bundle");
    // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
    using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (jsonURL, version))
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("WWW download had an error: " + www.error);
        }

        AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
        if (AssetName == "")
        {
            Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);
        }
        else
        {
            Instantiate(bundle.Load(AssetName));
        }

        bundle.Unload(false);

    } 
}
```

However, when I implement this, my test method claims to not be set to an instance. I don't want to make a new copy of these scripts as I would need to reset the link each time. Is there a way I can get this to work?

The error I get is as follows:

> An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(System.Collections.IEnumerator)'

Comment: yeld return null? Is your consumer ready to consume null enumeration values (for spinning?). I'd suggest to replace that with a proper delay mechanism (sleep, spinwait or a true synchronization object).

Comment: Do you know about `deferred execution`? Because your `DownloadAndCache` method does not make much sense that way. It seems like you are abusing the yield-feature for something else.

Comment: The second method is a Unity example of how to download their asset bundles. Whilst it probably does has issues, it works just now and isn't what I'm having issues with. Have I worded my question wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually doesn't have anything to do with coroutines.

It happens because you are trying to call **two** instance methods from a static method. That is, `DownloadAndCache` and `StartCoroutine` are instance methods, they are not static so they need an instance of its class `Foo` to execute.

`DownloadAndCache` could be static, so you wouldn't need an instance, but you won't get away without a MonoBehaviour instance to call `StartCoroutine`.